# java script function not working in windows

Tags: javascript

```
function bookingchanneldisable(stopSale){
     if (stopSale == "N") {
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannel").readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannelReservation").readOnly = false; 

      }else{
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannel").checked = true ;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannelReservation").checked = false ;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannel").readOnly = true;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannelReservation").readOnly = true; 
      } 
}
```

this function working fine in firefox (ubuntu) , but it is not working in firefox (windows). please can you help me

Comment: issue is ".readOnly"  not supporting , as solution i used disabled attribute but it create another issue

Comment: any error in your console

Comment: No , no any console errors

Comment: ".readOnly" is supported in every major browser including firefox. That's probably not the point. What exactly is not working? Debug it using FireBug and provide some more information please.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML (or a representative example)?

Comment: *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` prevents users from changing the field value. So it works with inputs in which you can change the value (like text boxes), but it doesn't work on inputs in which you do not change the value but the field state (like checkboxes).

To solve the problem, you should use `disabled` with checkboxes instead. Like this:

```
function bookingchanneldisable(stopSale){
     if (stopSale == "N") {
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannel").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannelReservation").disabled = false; 

      }else{
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannel").checked = true ;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannelReservation").checked = false ;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannel").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("applicableBookingChannelReservation").disabled = true; 
      } 
}
```

See it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fg1xLr1h/

Comment: As a side note, in theory the correct value to use with `disabled` is "disabled"; and with `readonly`, it's "readonly" as [specified in the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html)